# Creating restricted members area in Angular Fire 2

Tags: authentication, typescript, firebase, angularfire2

I am trying to make an application using angularfire 2. Can't find the perfect way to make the members area restricted that means only authenticated members can access that area. Here is my 'login.component.ts' file

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, AuthProviders, AuthMethods } from 'angularfire2';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
})

export class LoginComponent {

    state: string = '';
    error: any;
    login: FormGroup;

    constructor(
        public af: AngularFire,
        private router: Router
        ) {
        //official angfire 2 app example
        //this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => console.log(auth));
        }

ngOnInit() {
this.login = new FormGroup({
  username: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  password: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
});

}

onSubmit() {
    //console.log(this.login.value, this.login.valid);
    var value = this.login.value;
    //console.log(value.username);
    //console.log(value.password);
      this.af.auth.login({
      email: value.username,
      password: value.password,
    },
    {
      provider: AuthProviders.Password,
      method: AuthMethods.Password,
    }).then(
      (success) => {
      console.log(success);
      this.router.navigate(['/members']);
    }).catch(
      (err) => {
      console.log(err);
      this.error = err;
    })
  }

}
```

and the members.component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, AuthProviders, AuthMethods } from 'angularfire2';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
selector: 'app-other',
templateUrl: './members.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./members.component.css']
})

export class MembersComponent implements OnInit {
//name: "";
//state: string = '';

constructor(
  public af: AngularFire,
  private router: Router
  ) {

  this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => {
    if(auth) {
      console.log(auth);
    }
  });

}

logout() {
   this.af.auth.logout();
   console.log('logged out');
   this.router.navigate(['/login']);
}


ngOnInit() {
}

}
```

I know my code may be seem like a dumb one but actually I am trying to study over this. But there is not enough documentation to solve my problem I guess. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

https://coursetro.com/posts/code/32/Create-a-Full-Angular-Authentication-System-with-Firebase

this is a great tutorial that solves your problem